# Flutter как уменьшить размер проэкта для упаковки архиватором Zip?

Tags: flutter

Для резервного копирования flutter проэкта запаковываю его в Zip архив с временной меткой. Но почему то готовый размер такого архива с кодом простейшей программы около ~ 300мб. Если брать такой же андройд naitive проэкт, например на котлин, то он займет при архивации всего ~ 30мб. Подскажите, что можно выкинуть из проэкта, для того что бы уменьшить размер после архивации.

Comment: `Для резервного копирования`, лучше использовать git и хостнг для проектов, такие как github/gitlab/др.

Comment: Я знаю, что лучше использовать контроль версий, но у меня детские проэкты и нет смысла в этом направление двигаться. Тем более у flutter как то подозрительно мало боилерплейтерного кода и файлов которые используются в проэктах.

Comment: `мало боилерплейтерного кода` это зависит от того, как вы будете писать проекты)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнить `flutter clean`, это очистит Build cache (которые так много весят).

1 вариант:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 вариант:

В консоли ввести (непосредственно в проекте): `flutter clean`

Comment: Спасибо! Запакованный проэкт стал размером 300кб.